# Tensorflow MNIST using convolution parameters

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I dont understand why in [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/pros/) he use  the  bias_variable of size 32, as i know the bias num is equal to num of neurons in the layer and in this case the number of neurons in the first layer is equal to 28 because the image pixels = 28 and he use the `padding = "SAME"`, why it is equal 32 not 28?

Comment: In the first convolution layer they have chosen to use 32 5x5x1 kernels. Each kernel, after convolution, will produce a feature map and will need its own bias value. Given you have 32 kernels, 32 bias values are used. This is independent of how large your input images are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that mnist is using convolutional networks, not conventional neural networks and hence, you are dealing with convolutions(not neurons) and in this example , and in convolutions you commonly use a bias for every output channel, and this example uses 32 output channels in the first convolution layer and that gives you 32 biases.

Comment: Thanks but  what i know is that every hidden layer consists of feature maps which contain neurons but i think 32 bias because one bias is shared to all the neurons of the one filter.

Comment: Yep, feature maps is the same as output channels, and because convolutional networks use shared weights across kernels(also called patchs) in convolution layers, that would mean one bias by every output channel(or feature map)  and as you say this bias will be shared across patches.

Answer (score 0):

They use bias of size 32 to be compatible with the weights:

```
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
```

They use weights in conv2d function `tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')`.

[tf.nn.conv2d()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) tells that the second parameter represent your filter and consists of `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`. So `[5, 5, 1, 32]` means that your `in_channels` is 1: you have a greyscale image, so no surprises here.

32 means that during our learning phase, the network will try to learn 32 different kernels which will be used during the prediction. You can change this number to any other number as it is a hyperparameter that you can tune.